# Which layer of a MVC + SOA application should contain the permission enforcement?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, architecture, soa

I'm looking to get an opinion or best practice regarding which layer(s) is best suited to hold the permission enforcement in an application (View, Controller, Service, Model)

For example, knowing that the <strike>M</strike>VC is/could be just another consumer of the service layer, does that suggest that permissions may not be enforced at the controller and/or view level?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/220574/where-should-user-permission-checks-take-place-in-and-mvc-and-by-who

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like anything, it depends, it's up to you, and is debatable and up to opinion. If it works for you, do it.

Now, in my opinion, I like to put it in the controllers. Why?

1. Microsoft already provides tools to do it there. Including data annotations and that IPrincipal thingy.
2. The controller is the entry to your app. It makes sense to have the locks at the entry.
3. Your Service can be decoupled from your application users, which means you can re-use your service in a completely different applicattin which handles permissions differently.